# Javascript - confusion between global & local variable

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables, local

**EDIT2**: Here is the console log. The image is being converted to canvas (HTML5), I need to 'return' this to the global variable somehow. Suggestions?

```
<img id="mainIllustration" alt="main illustration" src="Img/Model01.png">
Illust...o_03.js (line 24)
<canvas id="mainIllustration" class="" width="278" height="659" style="" title="" tabindex="-1">
Illust...o_03.js (line 32)
<img id="mainIllustration" alt="main illustration" src="Img/Model01.png">
Illust...o_03.js (line 24)
<canvas id="mainIllustration" class="" width="278" height="659" style="" title="" tabindex="-1">
Illust...o_03.js (line 32)
<img id="mainIllustration" alt="main illustration" src="Img/Model01.png">
Illust...o_03.js (line 24)
<canvas id="mainIllustration" class="" width="278" height="659" style="" title="" tabindex="-1">
```

**EDIT 1**: I am starting to wonder whether the issue is with Pixastic, the fact that its manipulating the image, which I need to return back to the global image variable (eMainIllustration). How would I achieve this?

**ORIGINAL MESSAGE :**

All,

Im using pixastic library and am getting very confused by a seemingly very simple thing, global/ local variable.

I have below two sets of code, one in which the variable is globally defined (ultimately what I want) & another in which the variable is locally defined.

The first code below works fine, the variable (eMainIllustration) is locally defined and the function works well.

```
    var eDisplayTableSlideState = false;
    function displayTableSlideIn()
    {
// eMainIllustration is locally defined
        var eMainIllustration = document.getElementById("mainIllustration");
        if (eDisplayTableSlideState === false)
        {
            $("#displayTable").animate ({top: "-=33px", left: "+=66px", width: "-=198px", height: "-=48px"}, 750, "swing",function()
            {
                Pixastic.process (eMainIllustration,"blurfast", {amount: 0.1});
            return (eDisplayTableSlideState = true);
        } else
        {
            $("#displayTable").animate ({top: "+=33px", left: "-=66px", width: "+=198px", height: "+=48px"}, 500, "swing",function()
            {
                Pixastic.revert(eMainIllustration);
            });
            return (eDisplayTableSlideState = false);
        }
    }
```

However, when I set the variable (eMainIllustration) globally, the first if statement of the function works, however the pixastic.revert code in the 'else' part of the function does not. Why?

```
// eMainIllustration is locally defined
var eMainIllustration = document.getElementById("mainIllustration");
    var eDisplayTableSlideState = false;
    function displayTableSlideIn()
    {
        if (eDisplayTableSlideState === false)
        {
            $("#displayTable").animate ({top: "-=33px", left: "+=66px", width: "-=198px", height: "-=48px"}, 750, "swing",function()
            {
                Pixastic.process (eMainIllustration,"blurfast", {amount: 0.1});
            return (eDisplayTableSlideState = true);
        } else
        {
            $("#displayTable").animate ({top: "+=33px", left: "-=66px", width: "+=198px", height: "+=48px"}, 500, "swing",function()
            {
                Pixastic.revert(eMainIllustration);
            });
            return (eDisplayTableSlideState = false);
        }
    }
```

I wonder if this is because I am not returning the state of the changed (eMainIllustration) via return in the first half (if) of the function. Is that correct? And how would I achieve this?

Best,

Comment: I wonder why so many people make JavaScript look like Java/C# :)

Comment: 1) Always be more explicit when saying something "doesn't work"; 2) comparing against booleans in an if statement is a general anti-pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.

In case anyone has any confusion of how Pixastic works, here is what my understanding, along with a solution to my problem.

The pixastic blurfast (& blur) plugin 'revert function' merely reverts the element back to its original state. In other words, you are not adding another effect but telling pixastic to cancel all the changes & replace the element with its original state.

Keep in mind that when a pixastic effect is added, the image is no longer an image but a HTML5 canvas element, which in this case, is being canceled and the original 'image' being put back in place.

The global variable & local variable problem with resolved by using the 'return' at the end of the function. Actually, this part was not the actual problem, the problem was with the revert implementation I (wrongly) was trying to implement.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you alert or console.log the variable out inside the function? Had my issues with defining global variables using functions.

Where i am going with this is that the DOM might not the ready. Try the use of:

```
if(window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        //DOM is now ready. Set your global variables value here.
    });
} else {
    //If internet explorer, use attachEvent method.
}
```

Comment: @user1027444, the function is attached to a button, so its not executed until the user presses the button. Also, the first part of the function works fine, however the 'pixastic.revert' (which is called when the button is pressed the second time) bit fails

Comment: @Kayote, as you can see in how he wants it to be he is using the getElement... On a global function. Which means it is not attached to any function or method. Which can result in that the DOM is not ready and he won't get the content he is looking for.

Comment: sorry Dannie, Im donot understand your comment. Its globally defined so by definition should be accessible to every function.

Comment: That is correct. But as you try to set a global variable to some object in the DOM(html element) it cannot be done. The DOM(Where all elements are stored) is not ready when you're trying to use it. You have to make an event that wait's for the DOM to be ready so you can find and use the element you wishes to.

Comment: tried it but nothings changed. Am getting the same problem, I can go back to using the local variable but I really want to know why the global variable is not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the location of your Javascript on the page.

If you have it at the top of your page then the mainIllustration dom element may not have loaded before the javascript is loaded.

If you move it to just above the body tag then the variable will be populated as the dom will be fully loaded by the time the javascript loads.

Thus it works when inside the function as the dom is loaded before you call the function, but does not work if it is outside the function.

```
var eMainIllustration = document.getElementById("mainIllustration");
```

---

Edit

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        load("path_to_javasript");
     });
</script>
```

Comment: I have the js file loaded at the bottom of the body tag, just before the body tag closes.

Comment: have tried the eventlistener as suggested by Dannie Hansen above but that doesnot solve either.

Comment: How about loading your javascript file when the document is ready - see edited answer

Comment: Thanks @Nicholas Murray, I am using the DOMContentLoaded function, pretty much the same as ready function, I presume. PLEASE see my edit 1 at the top of the post.